# Django template not loaded when deploy on openshift

Tags: python, django, templates, openshift, mezzanine

Totally new to Openshift and has been following various stepbystep guides.  Able to get django 1.6, Python 2.7 and Mezzanine 3.0.9 up with the application working - partially.  For some reason, the template is not loaded, both if the template is part of a HTML include tag or a part of view.py.

When tailing access-log, cannot see errors or anything to go by.  The settings.py has

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PROJECT_DIRNAME = PROJECT_ROOT.split(os.sep)[-1]
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),)
```

It seems to not be able to find the path of the template files but don't know why as the value of TEMPLATE_DIRS seems to be correct when checking it. Everything is working ok on my local machine but not on Openshift.  Any pointers are much appreciated as have been googling and search around for a few days and still get no where.

Thank you.

EDIT:
Decide to turn on DEBUG mode and that is a lot clearer to investigate.  Turns out that without providing absolute module name when importing a method the application just fail but this is not the case on local machine.
e.g. instead of providing 
    from projectname.appname.view  import some_function
I was putting
    from appname.view import some_function

Silly me.  That teach me a good few days lesson!!!durr!!

Comment: Sometimes Openshift gives trouble when passing certain files. I had problems with both static and media files too. It has to do with permissions in the folders, and permissions in build and deplyo scripts. Check if your template files actually exist in the templates dir under the deployed directory.

Comment: All the files are there.  Once providing a complete module name ie. project.app.file in import statement then it all works perfectly.

Comment: If the problem was solved, add an answer to your own question (yes, you can)

Comment: Err... i cannot answer my own question as i am new and thus less than 10 reputations.  The system suggests that I answer my own question after 8 hours or else edit my question which I did.  I will close it when the system allows.  Sorry about that and thank you Luis for your suggestion.

Comment: @green did you change your url.py ???

Comment: No.  I change all my imports statement to include a full path to the method.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved by providing a full module name to the import statement.
e.g.

```
    from projectname.appname.view import some_function
```

I had, see below, and that caused the issue.

```
    from appname.view import some_function
```

Once a full module name is provided, it all works perfectly.

Thank you.